# wordpress plugin translation to persian language

Tags: php, wordpress, poedit

i want to translate pagerestrict plugin to persian language.
 my textdomain is **'mimalef'** . **mimalef-fa_IR.mo** and **mimalef-fa_IR.po** are localed in **plugin_directory/languages** 
in the first line of pagerestrict.php (main file of plugin) added this code. but yet the translate does not appear:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'mimalef', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
```

**to download the modified plugin click** [here](http://mimalef.com/pagerestrict.zip) (it's only 67 KB)

Comment: You should send your persian translation to the Plugin author (e.g. by emailing him). He will thank you a lot for the new translation and integrate it into the Plugin. 

This way you do not have to modify the Plugin source code and you also contribute something to the WordPress community.